# How to maintain two values of single field in html

Tags: javascript, rounding, forms, http-post

I have a requirement, where i need to show rounded decimal value for the fields in the page. But if user doesn't change the field's value then i need to post the original value of field instead of rounded value and my external library will be called with this posted values.
For example if a have a field 'Initial Temperature' and its value 12.892433 in database, when i populate the field in the page it will be 12.9. Now if user doesnt change this value then i need to post the actual value which is 12.892433.

Can anyone suggest me the best way to do this. I dont want to pull data from the database once i have the posted data.

Comment: You can save the original value in `data-value` attribute!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Some code is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data-* attribute, which is used to store custom data private to the page. For example:

```
<span id="span" data-val="12.892433">12.9</span>
```

And you can get the value with JS:

```
var value = $("#span").data("val");
```

And if you want the value on the server side you can use an input hidden, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="value" id="value" value="12.892433">
```

Comment: I need the value in server side(on form submit). I cannot use the span here, it is input field